# HTML table to YAML conversion

Tags: html, html-table, yaml

I am using nokogiri to parse HTML data into YAML structuring. I am having trouble seeing how to make HTML tables human-reading in YAML format. Anyone with previous experience on this? If yes, please shed some light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done both directions (YAML -> HTML and HTML -> YAML) and the YAML to HTML is actually in the [`ruamel.yaml.cmd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml.cmd/0.2.0) package of which I am the author.

The HTML is a table, that is a given, I will assume it has a header. So lets take the following table with a header row with elements `A`, `B` and `C` and two data rows of numbers:

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
5  6  7
```

there are several ways you can represent this in YAML, here are two examples.

1. Top level is a mapping, the header value the key and the column the value in a sequence:

   ```
   A: [1, 5]
   B: [2, 6]
   C: [3, 7]
   ```
2. Top level is list and each element is a mapping of header value to data value:

   ```
   - A: 1
     B: 2
     C: 3
   - A: 5
     B: 6
     C: 7
   ```

I find the second one more intuitive, but it is more verbose as the header strings get repeated as scalars in every sequence element.

If your table has row "headers" and column headers you might rather opt for a toplevel mapping where the key is a sequence of row and column header and the value the contents of the cell.
Table:

```
  A B 
K 1 2
L 5 6
```

corresponding YAML:

```
[A, K]: 1
[A, L]: 5
[B, K]: 2
[B, L]: 6
```

Please note that with most YAML dumpers you have no control over the ordering of the keys in the mapping you want to produce, without uglifying the YAML with tags.

Once you have decided on the output format and parsed the table, it should be relatively easy to walk over the rows/columns and cells of the table to create the data structure that dumps to YAML the way you want it (that is what I did for the examples above, with Python and `ruamel.yaml`)